# How to dynamically change model rules in YII framework?

Tags: php, yii, yii-cmodel

I have form in YII and it needs to change model rules dynamically. Is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked for Yii's validation scenarios?

http://php-thoughts.cubedwater.com/2009/validation-scenarios/

Comment: I added:
array('username, email', 'required', 'on' => 'add') in user model and $model->validate('add') in controller but it gives me error

Comment: Yii has few built in scenarios, for validation while adding a new record, use "insert". similarly you can use "update" and "search" as well.